# How to send json request to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I wants to send some json parameter from HTML page with text area and I want to send json parameter written in this text area eg format. `{"name": "test", "description":"test", "price":100}`

But rails consider it as `{"{'name' : 'test', 'description' : 'test', 'price' : 100}"=>nil}` how do I send json parameter from text area to be readable from rails application.

Comment: Can you post the `code` of sending the `json`?

Comment: did you set? Content-Type: application/json (http://www.hashcode.eti.br/?p=481)

Comment: When you mention you're "sending" JSON params - how are you doing this? Can you detail how you're sending them?

Comment: yes I set Content-Type: application/json but rails doesn't understand what has been passed from text area(json format). You can easily understand from this sample `<input type='textarea' name='content' value='{"name": "test", "description":"test", "price":100}' id='text_content' />`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to parse that string on server side with JSON.parse

```
param = '{"name" : "test", "description" : "test", "price" : 100}'
# assume you got the param on server side
json_param = JSON.parse(param)
puts json_param['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the comment:

> You can easily understand from this sample:

```
<input type='textarea' name='content' value='{"name": "test", "description":"test", "price":100}' id='text_content' />
```

You just sent a string to Rails in this way.

If you do the submit with a form, you should use different inputs for different params.

If Javascript, maybe jQuery, you can do it with function `$.post`.

Rails would parse the json for you.